# Align two inline divs along the bottom, on either side

Tags: html, css

I am looking to dynamically align the following two elements along the bottom of the container, such that they occupy opposite corners. Similar to how the `Stackoverflow Logo` and the `Ask Question` are bottom aligned, but on opposite corners of their container.

You can see the JFiddle test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/M5BuZ/

[image: Screenshot of the JFiddle test]

More interestingly, I would prefer this to work without adding a fixed margin space to the `right` element. That way, if the `left` element should grow in height, the alignment will be maintained.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the left element will be the only one changing in height? If this is the case, this should work for your situation based on your jsfiddle:

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#left, #right {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: #ccc;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  /* ie6/7 */
  *display: inline;
}
#right {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

So making the container position: relative; will enable you to position the right element as absolute and place it wherever you'd like without affecting how the container behaves (this is also assuming your left element will always have a larger height than the right).

EDIT: New [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajMaHall/M5BuZ/2/)

Comment: Is there any way we can have it size to either the left or the right?